# ZeroSSL credits (rthese same domain, but I cant' renew)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, zerossl

I have a expiored in some days SSL cert in zeroSSL panel, but I cant't renew it becouse I have 3/3 certificates generated. 1 is still active, but other two is Expired (it has been generated early for these same domain). Is it possible to delete somehow one of them and renew existing in these same free acoount?

Answer (score 1):

ZeroSSL provides 3 certificates for each free account.

The free certificate quotas **are not** including ***lifetime renews*** service.

It can be generated once and can't renew.

You can create a **new** account with a new email address ([I recommend using Temp Mail for unlimited temporary email address.](https://temp-mail.org/en/)) to obtain extra 3 new certificates.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean you can only generate 3 certificates over the lifetime of the account? Or can you only generate 3 certificates at a time, but when one expires you can renew or replace it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are no dedicated hosting. `Certbot` will help you to install and renew the SSL certificate automatically. Visit [Certbot instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions) to know more. It allows you to install free SSL certificate.